# Model properties null when making Jquery/Ajax call .net core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Model properties are always null when making jquery/ajax call in .net core. Any idea what is the issue here

```
var fileType = {
    fileTypeDescription: fileTypeDescription,
    isActive: isActive,
    sortOrder: sortOrder,
    CreatedDate: null,
    CreatedBy: null,
    ModifiedDate: null,
    ModifiedBy: null
};            

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { a: fileType },
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    }
});
```

Model:

```
public class MdtFebFileType
{
    public int FileTypeId { get; set; }
    public string FileTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public int? SortOrder { get; set; }

}
```

Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public Response AddFileType(MdtFebFileType fileType)
{}
```

For the data part in the ajax call, I've tried the following as well, but none of them worked.

```
JSON.stringify({ model: fileType })
JSON.stringify(fileType)
JSON.stringify({ 'model': fileType })
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `[FromBody] MdtFebFileType fileType`?

Comment: That too didn't worked. When I tried that, the model class itself became null. Earlier class was there but properties were null.

Comment: Its just `data: fileType,` and remove the `contentType` option.

Comment: Now I'm getting the below error in console - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find the fix, would you mind sharing the solution? Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: I just added the fix that I used as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.post instead of $.ajax. This solved my issue.

Example

```
$.post(url, { fileTypeName: fileType })
                        .done(function (response, status, jqxhr) {

                        })
                        .fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {

                        })
```

Comment: There must be something *seriously* wrong with $.ajax to cause this much trouble with essentially every framework out there. I hereby vow to never, ever, use $.ajax for as long as I live (and also never in my afterlife, if I end up in hell, the Devil's underlings can torture me all they want).

Answer (score 4):

> Any idea what is the issue here

The mdoel data is not being sent in the correct format and as such it is not matching the expected model by the controller action.

Two things to fix this.

First stringify the model as is in the client so that data is sent in the correct format

```
data: JSON.stringify(fileType),
```

and second you need to tell the action explicitly where to look for the model so the model binder can populate the model.

> `[FromBody]`: Use the configured formatters to bind data from the request body. The formatter is selected based on content type of the request.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddFileType([FromBody]MdtFebFileType fileType) {
    //...
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I made both changes and now I'm seeing the model class itself as null. Earlier class was there but properties were null. Thoughts ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this issue??